# IJCADでLISPを使いダイアログボックスにスライドファイルを表示したいのですが表示箇所が白色のまま表示できません

Tags: ijcad

IJCAD LISPヘルプを見ると(fill_image)と(slid_image)関数はサポートされているようなのですが、スライドファイルを表示する場所が白色のままでスライドファイルが表示されません。
（ちなみにCADの2Dモデル空間の色が黒色のとき白色となり2Dモデル空間の色が白色のときは黒色になります。）
また(fill_image)関数でcolor引数の値を色々変えてもスライドファイル表示部は白色のまま色は変わりませんでした。
(fill_image)関数に問題があるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

手元にあるIJCAD2018では問題なくDCLにスライドを表示することができました。
表示するスライドのフォルダがサポートファイルの検索パスに含まれているかどうかや、絶対パスが指定してあるかどうかを確認してみてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: IJCAD 2019 STD64bit体験版とIJCAD Mechanical2018 64bit体験版を使用して動作確認をしており、パスの指定やファイル名の大文字小文字等を変えたりといろいろ試しているのですがDCLにスライドファイルを表示することができない状態です。体験版だと機能が制限されるとかあるのでしょうか？